# Can Dekko Silverfish paks be used in suitcases/luggage?

Tags: luggage, nature-and-wildlife, florida

We found a Silverfish in one of our suitcases when traveling home to Michigan from Florida. We want to sure any other hitchhiking Silverfish are killed. Will Dekko Silverfish packs work well?

Answer (score 1):

Silverfish like humidity.

I'd say normally wash all the things (clothes...) that you brought back from Florida.

Make certain everything is dry after that.

Clean up your luggage, again make certain they are dry and stay dry. You can buy some desiccant packets and place them in your luggage and in your shoes.

From what I can read on the *internets*, you could put a dekko pack in your luggage.